# Python - Write list values in xlwt

Tags: python, list, xlwt

I have a **list** of **lists** in **Python**. I want to **write** individual list as a row in [xlwt](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
 datalist = [['India', 'Yes', '99%'], [['China', 'Yes', '89%'], ['Brazil', 'No', '90%']], ['Russia', 'Yes', '92%'], [['Germany', 'No', '97%'], ['Spain', 'No', '70%']]]
```

First I calculated the total number of **list** def count(local_list):

```
def listcount(lst):
  listsum = 0
  for item in lst:
    if not isinstance(l,list):
      return 1
    else:
      listsum+= listcount(item) 

  return listsum
```

**excel_export.py**

```
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet("PySheet1")


for rownum in range(listcount(datalist)):
  row = sheet.row(rownum)

  for index, col in enumerate(datalist):
    # do something similar like in listcount()
    # check if instance is list if not then write the value
    # rownum will act as a row
    # column value will come from list item

    row.write(row, col, val)


book.save("test.xls")
```

**Samplesheet**

[image]

**How can I write list value in appropriate row and column?**

Comment: add sample Excel output table.

Comment: @VedangMehta- Excel sample added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much simpler to deal with the weird structure of the list once and for all from the beginning:

```
datalist = [['India', 'Yes', '99%'], [['China', 'Yes', '89%'], ['Brazil', 'No', '90%']], ['Russia', 'Yes', '92%'],
            [['Germany', 'No', '97%'], ['Spain', 'No', '70%']]]

new_datalist = []
for lst in datalist:
    if isinstance(lst[0], list):
        new_datalist.extend(lst)
    else:
        new_datalist.append(lst)
datalist = new_datalist

print(datalist)
```

Output:

```
[['India', 'Yes', '99%'], ['China', 'Yes', '89%'], ['Brazil', 'No', '90%'], ['Russia', 'Yes', '92%'], ['Germany', 'No', '97%'], ['Spain', 'No', '70%']]
```

Now you can write the values to the sheet in a straightforward manner. You can also get rid of `listcount`.

Comment: You're rain maker Alex Hall!